# phonegap camera API does not fire SuccessCallBack mthod on Attach of caprured image

Tags: android, cordova, webview, camera

I am using the Phonegap API to capture an image.

Once i take the picture and attach it my success call back method is not called .

Here is how i have implemented it.

1. I have added the Phonegap.jar file to the libs also added this to the build path .
2. And on my Main Activity which extends the DroidGap class i specify 
   super.loadUrl("http://test.someU.com/Android/testandroid.html");
3. This page testandroid.html contains a reference to the PhoneGap.js script file also another js called the main .
4. On click of the camera button the camera opens but on attach of the captured image the success callback method is not called .

   ```
   function dump_pic(data) {
       alert(data);        
   }

   function fail(msg) {
       alert(msg);
   }

   function show_pic() {
       navigator.camera.getPicture(dump_pic, fail, { quality: 50 });
   }
   ```

On successfull attach of the taken picture it has to call the dump_pic with it base64 data being alerted nothing happens.

Now , If i implement the same but with slight differences 
That is i under the assets folder have a www folder under which i have a file say index.html and the same above code the only difference here is the super.loadUrl 
method changes to super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); as the phonegap example does it in that case everything just works fine it called t he success call back method also the failure method in case of a failure .

The application i have implemented is a web app and has to work some how by the first method . Any idea as to how to get through this . Thanks any help is greatly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is correct behaviour of a phonegap app for security reasons.

If you could access the camera from a webpage loaded in the Webview this would open a lot of possible security hazards.

You have to load the camera from the local index.html file.

Take a look in how to deploy your app on the phone und and use market place for updates.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, However someone seems to have done it here on a flash player (http://www.flashmobileblog.com/2010/03/12/flash-player-10-1-camera-support-phonegap/ ) I am looking for something similar in my aspx page

Comment: From the OP's description, PhoneGap _is_ already accessing the camera, at least enough to start it, despite having been invoked from a remote URL.