# Include jar in aspx or html

Tags: java, asp.net

Is it possible to include a JAR file in an aspx page . If so how do i go about this ???
Thanks in Advance

Comment: *include a JAR file in an aspx page* Can you please elaborate

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: Probably a dump question :) .Anyways here goes the thought . I am using the Phongap API to access the camera on an android phone 
 here the actuall post as to what really is happening http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947156/phonegap-camera-api-does-not-fire-successcallback-mthod-on-attach-of-caprured-ima

Answer (score 0):

Since aspx ends up being HTML to an UA, and Java supports applets, which can be embedded in HTML, the answer is yes.  As to the 'how', start with Google & 'Java Tutorial Applet'.

Comment: Thanks Andrew , The actual problem is mentioned here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947156/phonegap-camera-api-does-not-fire-successcallback-mthod-on-attach-of-caprured-ima And i think it is because of the PhonGap.jar file not being included that is causing the problem

Comment: So it's on Android is it?  You should add that tag to help me avoid wasting my time.