# PhoneGap, Camera callback function not called

Tags: cordova, callback, remote-server

I worked on a application built with PhoneGap. It should take photo (or take one in the librairy) and upload it on our server.

I can take a photo, but the callback function isn't called.
On [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5983608/1565111), I see that he has the same problem and my application is based on a remote server too. But I've not found so much informations...

Anyone can confirm me that he said ?

Is there some solution ?

I'm in the obligation to keep my webpages on the remote server because its used like a webapp too with jQuery Mobile. PhoneGap is just used to add native functionality...

Or maybe can I call a local script ?

Any help is highly appreciated...

Thanks!

EDIT: This is an iOS app...
I've got the result I want in the debug console, but the callback isn't called so I can't access to it.

2012-07-31 11:29:45.669 Invokit[1199:707] PluginResult:toJSONString - {"status":1,"message":"{{image_encodedbase64}}","keepCallback":false});